# Why Java did not check for type compatibility for byte as it does with int?

Tags: java, for-loop, integer, byte, primitive

I am trying to use byte as control loop variable in for loop.
I used the condition as n < 128 (where 128 is out of range of byte)

```
for (byte n =0; n < 128 ; n++) System.out.println("I am in For loop. "+ n );
```

The loop is going infinitely from 0 to 127 and then -128 to 127.

When I tried to do the same with int, it gave an error.

```
for (int n = 0; n < 2147483648; n++)
```

The literal 2147483648 of type int is out of range

Why did Java not check the type compatibility with byte like it checked for int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type compatibility is not checked against the type of the loop's variable.

The type of an integer literal with no suffix is always `int`. `128` is a valid `int`, so the first loop passes compilation but results in numeric overflow leading to an infinite loop.

On the other hand, `2147483648` is not a valid `int`, so the second loop doesn't pass compilation. If you replace `2147483648` with a `long` literal (`2147483648L`), the second loop will also pass compilation.

Answer (score 3):

With `n < 128` int comparison happens; n is propagated to an int. However any byte value as int is less than 128. And n++ overflows.

For the other case:

```
n < 2147483648L
```

would have been accepted and caused the same problem.